# Is It Possible to Limit # of iOS App Installs as a Developer?

Tags: ios

I'm building an educational iOS app and I'm wondering whether it's possible to limit the number of installations per user. I expect elementary schools to be one of my primary customers, however many schools use one Apple ID for all of their iPads, and therefor would only have to pay once for my app regardless of the number of iPads it's being installed on. Does anyone know whether it is possible for me to limit the number of devices it can be installed on based on the subscription fee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible.  A solution for this is to have the subscription tied to an account and require the user to log in.  If you do that then you can ensure that only one user is logged in per account.

If you are using a framework that allows you to see the device UUID then you could also tie the subscription to that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service and ensure that only N number of apps are open at any time for each account. It's essentially what Netflix and other subscription based services do.

In any case, there's no way for the App Store to validate your service subscription before allowing people to download the app.

Comment: Okay, that was my plan B. Thanks